# Contact Form on WordPress Sites?

Tags: pages, contact, forms

How does one go about building a page in wordpress that contains a contact form full of custom fields, boxes, inputs, etc. completely determined by the author of the site. It seems odd that wordpress currently lacks this feature, but knowing the wordpress community, it's unlikely that we must do without.

Comment: Everyone seems to use Contact Form 7. It's good, but I've also built custom forms for this purpose.

Comment: Is the [wordpress-3] tag appropriate here? The question doesn't refer to WP3 specific functionality and could equally apply to earlier versions of WordPress.

Comment: I use [Enhanced WP Contact Form](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/enhanced-wordpress-contactform/) and it works for me, even though it says it only works up until WordPress 2.6 it still works fine for me using WordpPress 3

Comment: [dynamicwp-contact-form](http://www.dynamicwp.net/plugins/free-plugin-dynamicwp-contact-form/) comes with floating button on the webpage .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) is one of the most popular plugins to add a contact form to a WP blog. It supports multiple contact forms and you can add/remove fields as needed. Additional services such as reCAPTCHA and Akismet can be added. I use this on most of my blogs to power the contact features.

Comment: I use Contact Form 7 on all my sites. It also has several extension points (actions and filters) with which you can add your own custom functionality.

Comment: I've been very happy with Contact Form 7; One thing to check, if you use tools to migrate your database and replace URL's; make sure your generated e-mails are still correct. CF7 stores the line breaks as /r/n and some scripts read it wrong and re-write it to the database differently.

Comment: Contact Form 7 requires Javascript to be activated to work.

Answer (score 5):

One of the most common plugins used to do this is [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/).  There are also [numerous other free plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=contact+form&sort=) to add this functionality, as well as paid plugins such as [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/).

Answer (score 5):

Consider using [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/).  It's commercial but only $39 per site and it's one of the best $39 I've ever spent for WordPress development.

Comment: After looking through lots of other contact form plugins Gravity forms is the only one that I'd let my clients use. Nothing else even compares to how easy and nice it is to use.

Comment: Soooo glad that I checked this site before going with Contact 7 forms. Gravity forms is seriously unbelievable. Thanks @MikeSchinkel, you saved me hours worth of work today.

Comment: *@jessegavin* - Glad I could be of service.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel: Is the Gravity Forms Plugin not GPL'ed?

Comment: @hakre - I believe it is licensed GPL, why? But it's not available directly from the vendor by download without paying. Are you suggesting that because it is GPL that people should look to get it for free rather than pay the reasonable amount to help fund its continued development and support?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - why? I just was curious, the website didn't specify that and as you wrote you're using it I hoped you knew. And I'm not suggesting what you think, GPL'ed software can be sold and I always suggest to pay a dev/support.

Comment: @hakre - Here's [the official(?) answer regarding Gravity Forms and GPL](http://www.gravityhelp.com/forums/topic/is-it-gpl). As a side note, I know that you personally champion a lot of issues related to GPL but I've never understood why it was so important to you? I'm not at all questioning your reasons, I respect your right to free speech and to champion a cause you believe in, but I've just been very curious why it's so important to you to devote so much energy to advocate on behalf of GPL in the WordPress space?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - Thanks for the link, that's the kind of info I was looking for. Regarding your ask for info: It's not about Free Speech but about Free Software: For WP and derivates I've contributed code under the GPL that's why I care. I couldn't imagine any better reason, it's my license. And more generally I'm interested in the freedom of software, as most of my friends and customers are as well. So to find out if a certain plugin is actually meeting the needs, licensing has its part in that. A problem with plugins is normally that you don't get correct and precise infos upfront for some.

Comment: @hakre - I see what you mean, but we all make choices in where we devote time and if you devote time advocating for GPL that means you don't devote that time for other things. I guess I wonder why this issue is so important to you that it consumes so much of your time? I understand why Richard Stallman does it, GPL is basically his career, but what value do you get that's worth more to you than other things you could spend your time on? *(Again, I'm only just really curious what drives you on this issue?)*

Comment: Because it's basically part of my job Mike. It's worth the time and the discussions. I think it's the same why you devote time to answer questions on this site. Because we learn with what we do. I have no problem to devote my time into something, even/especially not if it's passionate.

Comment: @hakre - Ah, that helps. Thanks. May I ask then, what specifically do you do for a living?  If you are interested, you can see what I do in my profile here on the site.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to do a highly custom form, and want complete control over what happens, you can also create a new template for the page, and your form on that template would post back to itself.  At the top of the template you could do something like this:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
     // do something
}
?>
```

Not the most elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Add me to the Gravity Forms supporters list. Of course it does a lot more than just contact forms. You should definitely check out the feature list and decide if it is worth your $39 dollars. It was a no-brainer for me and I bought the unlimited site developer license.  The time that it saves me makes it worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been pleased with the (free) [Deko Boko forms plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/deko-boko-a-recaptcha-contact-form-plugin/). Flexible, easy to modify and recaptcha is integrated.

Comment: captcha is very bad and not the best usability

Comment: If I mention that captcha is not mandatory will you remove the -1?

Answer (score 1):

See the different- for only a form in one page it is easy and fast (no filter-hook or other) to write a template for a page in WP, for more flexibilty and functions us a plugin. A ready solution or a starter there you can find here: https://github.com/bueltge/WP-Contact-Form-Template

Answer (score 1):

## Secure Form Mailer Plugin For Wordpress

For years and years I have been using the form plugin from dagon design: http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/secure-form-mailer-plugin-for-wordpress/ for free! (so let me do my happy user giveback thing:)

This plugin has a wide range of features including:

- Support for multiple instances
- An easy to use dynamic form generation system (any number of fields, in any order)
- multiple recipients
- multiple file attachments
- optional auto reply feature
- an image verification system
- numerous security features (including protection against email header injection)
- a message template system
- multiple languages
- and too many other things to list.

This plugin was designed to be easy to use, while still being extremely flexible. If you just want a simple contact form, you can set one up with just a few clicks.

For those of you who need something a bit more advanced, you can completely customize the plugin to fit your needs – whether it is 5 fields or 500. A non-WordPress version is also available. ReCaptcha support has also been added, as well as support for storing the data in a delimited file.

It has served me well for years.

Answer (score 0):

Plus one for gravity forms as I have found it to be much easier for my clients to use. Is easier to provide theme support for (ie Easier to customize via CSS) and has fewer conflicts with other plugins

Comment: If you want to "plus one," use the up arrow on the answer that already exists and/or add a comment explaining WHY you "plus one".

Answer (score 0):

There is as well the [**Grunion Contact Form** (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/grunion-contact-form/) which is quite simple to use. Just add a

```
[contact-form]
```

Shortcode inside a page or post. Job done. Can be configured as well.